# Errors installing pip on windows

Tags: windows, python-2.7, installation, pip, windows-shell

I was trying to install pip on windows in the windows command-line but when I test it, it gives me this error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xea' in position 11:
 ordinal not in range(128)
```

Here is the whole error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "c:\python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\__init__.py", line 207, in main
    cmd_name, cmd_args = parseopts(args)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\__init__.py", line 166, in parseopts
    parser.print_help()
  File "c:\python27\lib\optparse.py", line 1670, in print_help
    file.write(self.format_help().encode(encoding, "replace"))
  File "c:\python27\lib\optparse.py", line 1650, in format_help
    result.append(self.format_option_help(formatter))
  File "c:\python27\lib\optparse.py", line 1633, in format_option_help
    result.append(group.format_help(formatter))
  File "c:\python27\lib\optparse.py", line 1114, in format_help
    result += OptionContainer.format_help(self, formatter)
  File "c:\python27\lib\optparse.py", line 1085, in format_help
    result.append(self.format_option_help(formatter))
  File "c:\python27\lib\optparse.py", line 1074, in format_option_help
    result.append(formatter.format_option(option))
  File "c:\python27\lib\optparse.py", line 316, in format_option
    help_text = self.expand_default(option)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\baseparser.py", line 112, in expand_de
fault
    return optparse.IndentedHelpFormatter.expand_default(self, option)
  File "c:\python27\lib\optparse.py", line 288, in expand_default
    return option.help.replace(self.default_tag, str(default_value))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xea' in position 11:
 ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Please add the code you used to install pip

Comment: and it should appear something like pip options

Comment: did u try downloading get-pip.py from here https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/ and ran python get-pip.py?

Comment: I followed the steps here in this youtube:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yHtFeEZEexc @KyleWilliamson

Comment: Pip is coming with python on windows, its located in Python27/Scripts

Comment: @TalesPádua If it comes with python why does it sends that error?

Comment: I have like 3 py files with pip name: 
 
- pip
- pip2.7
- pip2

Comment: You dont need to install it, you just need to put Python27/Scripts in your PATH to use pip from command line

Comment: I did it as it is in this image below:
https://i.gyazo.com/c45f2d772c5d4542a8b6aedefda66c64.png

I changed the 2 paths is it right? @TalesPádua

Comment: No, you got it wrong. You need to put `C:/Python27/Scripts` only on PATH on system variables, and you need to NOT DELETE PREVIOUS ENTRIES. You need to put it on the end of the path, separating each entry with `;`

Comment: To use a example, this is part of my PATH: `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Bitvise SSH Client`